# Закачка файлов из сети

Tags: xcode, сервер, ios, objective-c, синтаксический-анализ

Есть задача спроектировать простое приложение, которое будет выкачивать с сервера папку с изображениями и отображать их на iPad'е. За неимением опыта гуглил, и пришло понимание (возможно неверное) что я не могу получить доступ к файлам изображений напрямую. Как я понимаю, со стороны сервера мне нужен будет xml-файл(.plist) в котором будут записаны пути к файлам в этих папках. Будьте добры прокомментировать так ли это и если нет то каким образом реализовывается такая задача.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, вам будет нужен plist, json, soap, простой xml либо любой другой info-файл, в котором будешь указывать пути к ресурсам. 
Для подобных случаев у меня был опыт создания веб сервиса, который по твоему id генерировал json список твоих индентификаторов ресурсов. В паре с другим веб сервисом, который по индентификатору получал ресурс. С использованием SQL это все просто реализовалось. ИМХО это самый простой вариант, который подходит для долгого и активного пользования.

Comment: Благодарю, Александр!